# Asserting integer values in Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, automated-tests

I need to check if a searchresult is more than 500. I can get the actual search result to  print, but I'm having some trouble with the assertion that it is actually more than 500. This is what I have:

```
public void cucumberstuffblabla(Integer expectednumber)    throws Throwable {
waitForElementPresent(By.locator);

    int givennumber = Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.locator)).getText());

    Assert.assertTrue (givennumber, greaterThan(expectednumber));
```

Assuming the execptednumber integer is 500, the Assert is never giving me a propper assertion, but always a CannotResolveMethod.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
 Assert.assertTrue(givennumber < expectednumber);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has answer of your question, just update your one line from

```
Assert.assertTrue (givennumber, greaterThan(expectednumber));
```

to

```
Assert.assertTrue(givennumber < expectednumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you pass two arguments to AssertTrue it expects one is a message to print on failure. Here is the method signature:

```
assertTrue(java.lang.String message, boolean condition)
```

What you want to do is pass a boolean condition and optionally a message, so:

```
Assert.assertTrue("Given is less then expected", givennumber > expectednumber);
```